# getting 'for result in cursor.limit(-1)' error after using find_one()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm making a discord bot and I'm just trying to set a dictionary to be a post in my mongodb database. The code was working just fine yesterday but now no longer works and returns literally hundreds of errors

```
File "c:\Users\seamu\OneDrive\Documents\darragh\PythonBot\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    player = collection.find_one({'_id':'Darragh#6360'})
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1114, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1159, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1057, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1603, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1553, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1589, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 530, in get_server_session
    session_timeout = self._check_session_support()
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 514, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Users\seamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 216, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-02.tftue.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,cluster0-shard-00-00.tftue.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,cluster0-shard-00-01.tftue.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61bf7c08911cdfd633917844, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.tftue.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.tftue.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.tftue.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.tftue.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.tftue.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.tftue.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>]>
```

The code I was just using to test what gave the errors:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://DarraghHoyne:[password]@cluster0.tftue.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
db = cluster['discordBot']
collection = db['Users']

player = collection.find_one({'_id':'Darragh#6360'})
level = player['level']
print(level)
```

obviously I'm using `[password]` instead of my password.

I also tried setting players to `find({'_id':'Darragh#6360})` and then

```py
for x in players:
    player = x
```

but still got errors

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was because I was using the hotspot from my phone as I was in the car, instead of my home wifi, and that IP address didn't have access. Hence the connection failed errors